# How to fix "stack overflow (recursion too deep)" error in NetLogo Code

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to solve a "stack overflow (recursion too deep)" error that I have with my code in NetLogo. This code generates clusters of patches to designate as land cover classes in a neutral landscape model. However the set-cover procedure results in a "stack overflow (recursion too deep)"error.

I tried commenting out the grow-cover_cluster call in the  procedure in the grow-cover_cluster but it does not solve the problem

```
to generate-landscape
  set cluster-area-list []
  set_random_seeds ;; randomly distribute 
  cluster seeds (Step 1 in Saura & Martinez-Millan 2000 p.664)
  set-cover ;; identify and label clusters (Steps 2 & 3 in above)
  fill_landscape ;; fill remaining patches to dominant neighbour     
  ask patches [ set pcolor (cover * 10) + 5 ] ;; color patches by cover 
end

to set-cover
  loop
   [
    let seed one-of patches with [ ( cluster = nobody and pcolor = blue ) ]   
    ;; pick a random seed we haven't labelled yet
    if seed = nobody ;; if we have labelled all seeds stop
      [ stop ]
    ask seed
      [
        set cluster self ;; make the seed the "leader" of a new cluster
        set cover ( random Number-of-Types ) ;; assign as cover "leader" 
        grow-cover_cluster ;; generate rest of cluster
        set cluster-area-list fput count patches with [cluster = myself] 
        cluster-area-list
     ]
   ]
end

to grow-cover_cluster
  without-interruption 
  [
    let neighbours nobody
    ifelse(Neighbourhood = "Moore")
    [ 
    set neighbours neighbors with [ cluster = nobody and pcolor = [pcolor] of myself ] ]
[ 
   set neighbours neighbors4 with [ cluster = nobody and pcolor = [pcolor] of myself ] ]
    ask neighbours
    [
      set cluster [cluster] of myself ;;make neighboring patch to seed cluster
      set cover [cover] of myself ;;make neighboring patch to patch cover
      set cluster_ID [cluster_ID] of myself
      ;grow-cover_cluster ;;recursive call!
    ]
   ]
end
```

The code should generate randomly seeded patches accumulating other surrounding patches to form clusters than eventually form cover classes in a neutral landscape model. However, the code in its current form above is generating a "stack overflow (recursion too deep)" error.

Comment: You have a recursive function which is calling itself and never terminating. You need a condition to trigger that will stop the function.

Comment: @mattsap given my current code, do you have any recommendations about how to exit the "forever" loop?

Comment: `without-interruption` should never be used, the fact that you're using it suggests you have some misconception about it or perhaps you've copied code that was written in a really really old NetLogo version

Comment: @SethTisue what would you suggest I use instead of without-interruption?

Comment: re: `without-interruption`, I guess that depends on what you imagined you were accomplishing by including it?

Comment: @SethTisue `without-interruption` is used so that each patch only gets added to the cluster once

Comment: The `cluster = nobody` checks should take care of that. (and `without-interruption` will not help with it)

Comment: @SethTisue Thank you for the insight. I still get the "recursion too deep error". I think it has to do with the grow-cover_cluster procedure calling itself within the procedure ... Is there a workaround you can suggest that accomplishes the required recursion without the error?

Comment: Sorry, but it isn't obvious to me just from eyeballing your code what the problem is. Similar code in Patch Clusters Example, in the Code Examples section of NetLogo's Models Library, works fine without an additional exit condition. Not sure what else to say besides “you have some debugging to do”. Perhaps standard debugging techniques such as adding `print` statements to trace the execution of the code will help.

Comment: @SethTisue Thanks for Patch Clusters example reference to inbuilt models library. Useful!